# How to convert base 7 to base 19 directly

Tags: arithmetic, number-systems

Is it possible to convert base 7 to base 19 directly without first converting to base 10 ?

If so, what is the algorithm ?

Comment: Yes­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: Yes. 10 isn't special; it's just the number after 9. It only seems special because we've chosen it as the usual base we work in.

Comment: @Awesome sorry I kind of mistold what I was really trying to ask

Comment: @user2357112 any algorithm that you can suggest in pseudo code ?

Comment: The algorithm is the same one you'd use to convert from base $7$ to base $10$, except for the obvious.

Comment: Same exact algorithm you'd use for converting from base 10 to base 19, except with all the 10s switched out for 7s.

Comment: @Cemre Why didn't you Google first what will you ask before posting your question here? Anyway, answer of your question may refer to this [link](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55984.html). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Work in base nineteen. Calculate the powers of $7$ in base nineteen, multiply them by the base-7 digits of the original number, add together.
2. Work in base seven. Start with your original number, successively divide by nineteen (that is, $25_7$), and remember the remainders; these become your base-nineteen digits.

The first method has the advantage that you don't need to do long division; on the other hand you need a nineteen-by-nineteen multiplication table. And long division by a two-digit number is not that cumbersome.